# C# Calling up a website and writing and reading the website in the background of a form application

Tags: c#, html, web

I wrote a form of application. When I start this, a web server (from a Siemens PLC) should be started in the background when starting (the call should only be made in code, the web browser should not open with the website visibly)
After the page has been called up in the code, the login fields (user name and password) should be filled / described automatically and logged in using the login button.
Then I would like to query / read status messages from the web server. What is the best way to implement this? You will then find a section of the HTML code for the login area. I thank you very much in advance and hope you can help me.

[HTML Code Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/934j3.png)

Comment: I may suggest to try with this: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp. I used it with success, but I never faced the problem of logging a website in.

Comment: You don't "start a web server" (that's the server at the other end that you connect to), nor do you need to run a browser. You use `HttpClient` to make requests from your application to the web server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client